# How to get the name of the Google doc only with js?

Tags: javascript, google-docs-api

I have a link to the google doc in this format:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/googleDocId/edit

When I post it in slack or skype, these programs  display me the real name of this doc:

[image]

[image]

I need to display "Test document" name on my site. Is it possible to do it only with javascript? Without creating any services on the server?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `get` method of the `Google Drive's API` which takes one required field which is the `fileId` which will be `15vISe8Lw841LqdVRtZM3egniCeRcsPXtivqxuh76t6o` in your case,

To retrieve your file metadata programatically, Try this,

```
function printFile(fileId) {
  var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
    'fileId': fileId
  });
  request.execute(function(resp) {
    console.log('Title: ' + resp.title);
    console.log('Description: ' + resp.description);
    console.log('MIME type: ' + resp.mimeType);
  });
}
```

I have tried with your document ID, and here is the output which I had received upon a successful response,

[image]

So you can use the `title` attribute to print your document tile in your site.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! It saves my day!

Comment: Great! Glad that it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

I created the full example based on the David's answer with loading needed api and getting fileId from the link:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script>
        function printFile(fileId) {
            var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
                'fileId': fileId
            });
            request.execute(function (resp) {
                console.log('Title: ' + resp.title);
                console.log('Description: ' + resp.description);
                console.log('MIME type: ' + resp.mimeType);
            });
        }

        function makeRequest() {
            var url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/15vISe8Lw841LqdVRtZM3egniCeRcsPXtivqxuh76t6o/edit',
                    fileId;

            fileId = url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/);

            if (fileId && fileId[0]) {
                fileId = fileId[0];
            }
            printFile(fileId);
        }

        function init() {
            gapi.client.setApiKey('your api should be here');
            gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2').then(makeRequest);
        }

        gapi.load('client', init);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```